# PHP issue with bind_param();

Tags: php, mysqli

Good day, I'm not really familiar with PHP and i get this error when i try to execute my query.

Warning:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in
>       /Users/site/userpanel.php on line 10

Code:

```
$query="SELECT SUM(gebruiker_id) AS totalitems FROM inventory WHERE gebruiker_id = 1";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $items);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->bind_result($col1);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mixing languages in code and/or database is considered a design flaw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a placeholder like this:

```
$query="SELECT SUM(gebruiker_id) AS totalitems FROM inventory WHERE gebruiker_id = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $items);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->bind_result($col1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! if i use ? as placeholder result will be 1 while it has to be 8 because gebruiker_id is in there 8 times

Comment: You to man! only it didn't fix my issue. it should return 8 as there are 8 rows in my table with gebruiker_id 1.

Comment: @J.Koppen And you are sure that `$items` is 1 and you also did `print_r($result);`? And i think you want to use `count()`

Comment: when i print $items it gives me nothing and when i print $result it gives me 1

Comment: @J.Koppen Did you even defined `$items` anywhere?!

Comment: Can you give me an example how i should use `COUNT()`

Comment: @J.Koppen This should work for you: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalitems FROM inventory WHERE gebruiker_id = ?` Also make sure `$items` is defined and is 1!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you don't need to bind:

```
$query="SELECT SUM(gebruiker_id) AS totalitems FROM inventory WHERE gebruiker_id = 1";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
//$stmt->bind_param("s", $items);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->bind_result($col1);
```

or

```
$query="SELECT SUM(gebruiker_id) AS totalitems FROM inventory WHERE gebruiker_id = 1";
$stmt = $db->query($query);
$result = $stmt->bind_result($col1);
```

But if you were trying to bind `$items` to `gebruiker_id` then follow `@rizier123` answer.

Comment: Let me explain this. I have to sum up how many times "gebruiker_id" 1 is in the table "items" (which is 8) and then result has to be 8.

Comment: @J.Koppen use `COUNT()`